# How to display certain category in the loop from WordPress default post type?

Tags: query-posts

I want to display a certain category from WordPress post type, but it is not showing...

Here is my quote. it displays all posts instead of "wedding venue" category post.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'category_name'  => 'wedding-venue',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'facetwp' => true,
);
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


//loop content here

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: What is `facetwp` argument for? Is the category slug correct?

Comment: That is to code to enable the https://facetwp.com/ filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it displays all posts... You create your own custom WP_Query, but then you ignore it and use global one ;)

Here’s the correct code:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'category_name'  => 'wedding-venue',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'facetwp' => true,
);
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query-> have_posts() ) : $query-> the_post(); ?>


//loop content here

<?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); // this should be inside if - there is no need to rested postdata if the_post hasn’t been called.
    endif; 
?>
```

PS. Remember, that if you want to modify posts that are displayed in main loop, you should use pre_get_posts action - creating your own query is redundant...

Comment: Hi Krzysiek, Thanks! that is work. The only issue is the facetwp filtering plugin not working, I think I have to check with facetwp filter plugin developer on this. Thanks again :)

Comment: really appreciate it